# Trying to write every file name, location and modification time, including subdirectories in c

Tags: c

Ok, so the goal is to pick a directory, look inside of it, and write the location followed by the modification date on a text file. If a directory is encountered within, it should open it and restart the search.

For now, the function "regarder" alone works quite well, but when trying to add the search in the subdirectories, that's where the problem begins
I know the detection of a directory works, and it seems to enter the regarder_dir function, but neither prints the names or writes in the file

Apologies for my potentially bad use of pointers, I have a bad time grasping how they work

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void ecrire(char * s);
void regarder(char * loc);
char regarder_dir(char * loc);

int main(void) {
    /*my main where i put where i want the search to begin */
    char localisation[10000]="C:\\Users\\ltonn\\Documents";
    regarder(localisation);
    return(0);
}

/*a function whose role is to write in the .txt file */
void ecrire(char * s){
    FILE * fichiertexte;
    fichiertexte = fopen(".\\liste.txt","w");
    fprintf(fichiertexte,s);
    fclose(fichiertexte);
}

/*the first called function which will return nothing but will write in the .txt file */
void regarder(char * loc){
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char contenu[10000];
    char position[1000];
    char modification[20];
    char surcontenu[10000];
    char souscontenu[10000];
    struct stat attrib;
    d = opendir(loc);
    strcpy(position, loc);
    if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        strcpy (contenu,dir->d_name);
        strcat(position,"\\");
        strcat(position,contenu);
        stat(position,&attrib);
        strftime(modification, 20, "%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%y", localtime(&(attrib.st_mtime)));
        if(S_ISDIR(attrib.st_mode)){
            strcpy(souscontenu, regarder_dir(position));
            strcat(surcontenu, souscontenu);
        }
        strcat(position,"\n");
        strcat(position,modification);
        strcat(position,"\n \n");
        strcat(surcontenu,position);
        strcpy(position,loc);
        modification[0]=0;
    }
    closedir(d);
  }
  printf("%s",surcontenu);
  ecrire(surcontenu);
}

/* the loop that should return the result of regarder for the directory at the position*/
char regarder_dir(char * loc){
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char contenu[10000];
    char position[1000];
    char modification[20];
    char surcontenu[10000];
    char souscontenu[10000];
    struct stat attrib;
    d = opendir(loc);
    strcpy(position, loc);
    if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        strcpy (contenu,dir->d_name);
        strcat(position,"\\");
        strcat(position,contenu);
        stat(position,&attrib);
        strftime(modification, 20, "%d-%m-%y", localtime(&(attrib.st_mtime)));
        if(S_ISDIR(attrib.st_mode)){
            printf("attempt at research \n");
            strcpy(souscontenu, regarder_dir(position));
            strcat(surcontenu, souscontenu);
        }
        strcat(position,"\n");
        strcat(position,modification);
        strcat(position,"\n \n");
        strcat(surcontenu,position);
        strcpy(position,loc);
        modification[0]=0;
    }
    closedir(d);
  }
  return(&surcontenu);
}
```

Comment: Allocating stack-based automatic arrays such as `char contenu[10000]` is not a good idea.

Comment: @jarmod so what do you recommend?

Comment: Either write the results as you go to avoid having to accumulate the data or, if you feel you need to accumulate the data before finally writing the results, then dynamically allocate the memory needed as you go. It will make the code more complex, admittedly, because you will have to maintain a variable length list of pointers or a linked list. If you can guarantee enough stack space at runtime then your current solution may be viable, but you don't have correct bounds checking right now so you will potentially overwrite your stack.

Comment: @jarmod ok thanks, i'll try that, i'll keep you updated about the result

Comment: @jarmod So, i removed the surcontenu var, and it should write as it goes, now the new problem is that it will loop on itself when trying to look inside the directory.
maybe i should open a new question thread

Comment: One major error is `regarder_dir`'s return type `char` instead of `char *`.

Comment: https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/main/c/opendir.c is an implementation that basically does what you're looking for.  Might be helpful.

Comment: Well in the meantime i did other things, so the code is less "sketchy", so the problems here are outdated, but thank you for trying to help